# Why doesn't <iframe> work properly for me?

Tags: html, css

I have a simple bit of HTML code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>iframe Practice</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <iframe src="//embed.gettyimages.com/embed/183351352?et=dbA2ZDFzQUqFbu8nRMfGww&sig=ozPqnsmwjm88sptsMM2UVS70lzd2ci-9q27BF6R0TzU=" width="507" height="407" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

When saved with .html extension and opened in a multiple browsers, I get a message saying "The file or directory could not be found." This is a very silly question, can somebody help me out with this?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried copying and pasting the iframe src into your browser? The iframe src must be a proper url....

Comment: your url does not have a protocol... http://url_here

Comment: @cale_b — Copy/pasting relative URIs rarely works well.

Answer (score 3):

You are using a scheme relative URI (one that begins with `//`).

This preserves the current scheme, so the content will load if you view it in a document hosted on `http:` or `https:` (normally you would get a security error if you tried to load an `https:` document into an `http:` document or vice versa).

You appear to not be using a web server, so you are trying to access the document via `file:` where it is not available.

You can either use an explicit scheme (replace `//` with `http://`) or do your testing on a web server (you can install one on your development system).

I'd generally recommend picking the latter option, there are many issues that crop up when you are testing documents on `file:` and using a development server bypasses them all.

Answer (score 1):

Simply `"//embed...` in the `iframe` element's `src` property to `http://embed...`.

```
<iframe src="http://embed.gettyimages.com/embed/183351352?et=dbA2ZDFzQUqFbu8nRMfGww&sig=ozPqnsmwjm88sptsMM2UVS70lzd2ci-9q27BF6R0TzU=" width="507" height="407" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to load the file locally with file://xxxxxxx You can not load and iframe this way you need to run it with a web server